# Making a gradient loading circle

Tags: adobe-photoshop-elements

I was recently playing a game, and saw a nice loading indicator that I wanted to try making myself.

[image: Gradient Circle Loading Indicator]

I’m using Adobe Photoshop Elements 14, and I tried making a circle with a transparent center and seeing if there was a paint-bucket-like tool for gradients. Unfortunately I couldn’t find a way. So is there a way this can be done in elements or do I need Photoshop CC?

Comment: Draw rectangle, erase part that shouldn't be visible with soft brush.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it is using the Elliptical Marquee Tool to select a circle with the shift key. After that I used the Gradient Tool for the gradient and added a white circle on top.

[image: Loading Symbol]